# Wrong use of enumerate

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code: I have this array of tot

```
[112 100  22  90  12  48 115  85  13  40  99  93 100  27  21  14  23 100]
```

I defined a random solution function:

```
def randomSolution():
    somma = 0;
    for i in enumerate(tot): 
        if somma<=3600: 
            countS[i] = 1
            somma = somma + tot[i]
        else: 
            break
    return countS
rand_sol = randomSolution()
print(rand_sol)
```

but Jupiter lab underlines me

> Index Error: too many indices for array.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try this: `for i, _ in enumerate(tot):` - [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple of `(index, value)` from the thing you're enumerating.

Comment: Do `print(list(enumerate(tot))` and this should make more sense. You likely meant `for i, elem in enumerate(tot):`.

Comment: There are a lot of problems in your code, can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is `countS`? You assign to it `countS[i] = 1` before creating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to be very forgiving of the way this questions was posed. I take it you are just trying to understand how to populate an array called *countS*

1. First things first, your array has no delimiters, which is a non-starter. I've added commas to help us get over this hurdled.
2. You never provided *countS*, so I just created an empty list for us to fill.
3. Because *countS* is originally an empty list, you can't index it iteratively. I replaced `countS[i] = 1` with `countS.append(1)` to append the new value iteratively to the list.
4. You may need a refresher on how to use `enumerate` because you are currently only unpacking the a single value. `enumerate()` returns the index position in list and the value at the index - so you need to unpack both with something like `for i, value in enumerate(tot):`

Here is the code that I got working - I hope this helps. In the future, please provide everything necessary to run your code so that we can help you more effectively.

```
tot = [112, 100, 22, 90, 12, 48, 115, 85, 13, 40, 99, 93, 100, 27, 21, 14, 23, 100]
countS = []

def randomSolution():
    somma = 0;
    for i, value in enumerate(tot): 
        if somma<=3600: 
            countS.append(1)
            somma = somma + tot[i]
        else: 
            break
    return countS
rand_sol = randomSolution()
print(rand_sol)
```

output

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Comment: yes, sorry, my question wasn't so clear, cause I'm not confident with python. I need to build step by step a simulated annealing algorithm and compare it with random and greedy solution